# For a Ktable-KTable leftjoin, putting tombstone(value = null) in the second table causes ValueJoiner to be called

Tags: scala, apache-kafka-streams

According to the documentation, semantics of KTable-KTable leftJoin [here](https://kafka.apache.org/20/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#ktable-ktable-join), if a tombstone(with a null value) is emitted to the second KTable(say by putting it into a topic behind the table), the ValueJoiner should not get called.
However the value joiner does get called with the second value being null.
This makes it hard to distinguish between the following cases

1. Tombstone emitted into the second KTable
2. Value emitted into the first KTable that has no matching records in the second KTable

Simplistic code below which demonstrates this:

```
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes
import org.apache.kafka.streams.{StreamsConfig, TopologyTestDriver}
import org.apache.kafka.streams.scala.StreamsBuilder
import org.apache.kafka.streams.scala.kstream.{Consumed, Produced}
import org.apache.kafka.streams.test.TestRecord

import java.time.Duration
import java.util.Properties
import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._

object LeftJoinBugReproduction extends App {

  val firstTopic = "first"
  val secondTopic = "second"
  val outputTopic = "output"

  val builder = new StreamsBuilder()

  private def stringSerde = Serdes.String()

  val table1 = builder.table(firstTopic)(Consumed.`with`(stringSerde, stringSerde))
  val table2 = builder.table(secondTopic)(Consumed.`with`(stringSerde, stringSerde))
  val joinedTable = table1.leftJoin(table2)(
    (v1: String, v2: String) => {
      v2 match { //set debug point here
        case null => v1
        case _ => s"$v1, $v2"
      }
    }
  )
  joinedTable.toStream.to(outputTopic)(Produced.`with`(stringSerde, stringSerde))
  val topology = builder.build()

  val props = new Properties()
  props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "my-app")
  props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "dummy")

  val topologyTestDriver = new TopologyTestDriver(topology, props)

  val firstTopicInput = topologyTestDriver.createInputTopic(firstTopic, stringSerde.serializer(), stringSerde.serializer())
  val secondTopicInput = topologyTestDriver.createInputTopic(secondTopic, stringSerde.serializer(), stringSerde.serializer())

  firstTopicInput.pipeInput(new TestRecord[String, String]("user1", "red")) //set debug point here
  topologyTestDriver.advanceWallClockTime(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
  secondTopicInput.pipeInput(new TestRecord[String, String]("user1", "blue")) //set debug point here
  topologyTestDriver.advanceWallClockTime(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
  secondTopicInput.pipeInput(new TestRecord[String, String]("user1", null)) //set debug point here

  val output = topologyTestDriver.createOutputTopic(outputTopic, stringSerde.deserializer(), stringSerde.deserializer())

  val outputLines = output.readKeyValuesToList()

  println(outputLines.asScala.mkString("\n"))

}
```

The output should be either

```
KeyValue(user1, red)
KeyValue(user1, red, blue)
```

or just
`KeyValue(user1, red, blue)`
depending on synchronisation situation of a particular execution.

However actually it is

```
KeyValue(user1, red)
KeyValue(user1, red, blue)
KeyValue(user1, red)
```

or just

```
KeyValue(user1, red, blue)
KeyValue(user1, red)
```

The not joined first record is emitted again because the ValueJoiner gets called for the tombstone into the second topic. Setting debug points in the value joiner and around the code where the input is being pumped in should make it clear.

Answer (score 1):

The observed behavior is correct. Note, that you are doing *stream processing* and thus, the result of the join is not a "snapshot table" but a continuously updated output table. Think about the result as a materialized view, that is updated each time the input tables are updated.

Thus, in your example you start with two empty input tables, and the result table is also empty:

```
left-table               right-table              result-table
+-------+----------+     +-------+----------+     +-------+----------+
| key   | value    |     | key   | value    |     | key   | value    |
+=======+==========|     +=======+==========|     +=======+==========|
+-------+----------+     +-------+----------+     +-------+----------+
```

When you send the first input record, you update the left input table, and thus the join is "recomputed" (ie, the join result table is updated *incrementally*) -- for this case, no join partner in the right table exist and thus a left join result is emitted:

```
left-table               right-table              result-table
+-------+----------+     +-------+----------+     +-------+----------+
| key   | value    |     | key   | value    |     | key   | value    |
+=======+==========|     +=======+==========|     +=======+==========|
| user1 | red      |     +-------+----------+     | user1 | red      |
+-------+----------+                              +-------+----------+
```

Next, you add a record to the right table, and thus the left join result changes to an inner join result:

```
left-table               right-table              result-table
+-------+----------+     +-------+----------+     +-------+----------+
| key   | value    |     | key   | value    |     | key   | value    |
+=======+==========|     +=======+==========|     +=======+==========|
| user1 | red      |     | user1 | blue     |     | user1 | red,blue |
+-------+----------+     +-------+----------+     +-------+----------+
```

Lastly, when you delete the right table record again, the result changes back to the left-join result:

```
left-table               right-table              result-table
+-------+----------+     +-------+----------+     +-------+----------+
| key   | value    |     | key   | value    |     | key   | value    |
+=======+==========|     +=======+==========|     +=======+==========|
| user1 | red      |     +-------+----------+     | user1 | red      |
+-------+----------+                              +-------+----------+
```

Thus, the result table is updated 3 times: first a new join result is added, and later the join result is update twice: first from left to inner and second from inner to left, such that the result of the output table is always aligns to the *current* data in both input tables.

Note, that the result table in your example contains a *single* output record (or zero in the beginning) at all times---it never contains *multiple* records.

Because you use `KTabel#toStream()` you observe the full *changelog stream* of the result table, that contains all 3 update records. Note, that the *semantics* of the output stream is *not* a cumulative "list" of records, but it's a changelog: each time a new record for the same key is emitted, it "overwrite/updates" the previous result for this key.

(Btw: actually, when you call `#toStream()` you change the semantics from a *changelog* to an *event* stream...)